# django doesn't print my dictionary value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
Category
Required: {u'Category': 4, u'Second Category': 12, u'Third Category': 3, u'Fourth': 11, u'Fifth': 0, u'Sixth': 8, u'Seventh': 5}
```

That is the output of

```
{{ category }}<br>
   Required: {{ required_per_category }} </td>
```

But when I do

```
 {{ category }}<br>
       Required: {{ required_per_category.category }} </td>
```

The output is `Required:` (empty).
Any idea?

Comment: This is only possible with a custom filter or tag (see the duplicate question).

Comment: Indeed, I solved it by looking at that other question. Thanks!